# After installing Ubuntu on Inspiron Duo, it appears/behaves like a desktop interface instead of a tablet

Tags: system-installation, tablet, inspiron

After I have installed the latest release to my Inspiron Duo, I am a bit confused about how I could get the desktop to appear and behave like a "real" tablet?

It is possible to have the OS as seen on the tablet page at ubuntu.com?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Desktop version. As "Convergence" has not yet taken place the "Tablet"/Ubuntu touch interface is not yet merged with the desktop experience.

You may be able to install it(in Ubuntu 13.10), but it is still something in development, and would not be a fully functional tablet experience, or fully integrated. More information about "Unity8Desktop" http://linuxg.net/unity-8-is-now-available-for-testing-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander/

To install, in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unity8
```

Then Type to launch:

```
unity8
```

**Again this is still in development, it is not done yet.**

Full desktop convergence may be delayed even further: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/ubuntu-tablet-will-key-focus-ubuntu-14-04-lts-cycle